# Regex: How to get the right most substring in a path

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a path like this:

```
"src/Re/sult/result.qrels"
```

I want to match the right most substring "result.qrels".

Currently I am using the regex:

```
(?<=/+)[^/]+
```

However this has three matches: `Re sult result.qrels`.

How could I express "right most" or "Greedy" in Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need look-behind, anchor your negated class to the end of the string.

```
[^/]+$
```

Depending on the language you are using a more logical approach would be to split:

```
result = 'src/Re/sult/result.qrels'.split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]+$

             ^^
```

Use `$` to indicate end of string part. See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/3

Comment: This solved something for me I hadn't been able to figure out on my own. I made two different versions delimiting with backslashes instead, and capturing the left and right hand sides. This one is similar with the lookbehind: https://regex101.com/r/zsRmcj/3  
This one omits the lookbehind but seems to work just as well, so I am curious if anyone could explain that in more detail (why not needed?): https://regex101.com/r/io14TO/1

Comment: @learning2learn we actually dont need lookbehind...its just as assertion for `/` . Regarding the two answers here...the output will differ if url is just `abc`.Then my regex will fail stating no `/` as it has lookbehind but the other one will pass.So depends on what you really require.